# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY - yet I have it installed

Tags: reactjs, npm

What exactly does this mean?
I have React 15.4 installed, yet it complains.
Not sure why the other two appeared.
What does the prepending + and  ` mean?

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY popper.js@^1.16.0  
+-- pretty-checkbox@3.0.3  
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.4.0
```

**Package.js**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "transport": "watchify js/app.js -v -t babelify -p livereactload -o public/js/bundle.js",
    "ES6-to-ES5": "npx babel es6 --watch --presets babel-preset-env --out-dir js",
    "watch": "gulp medicus-watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "browserify": "^14.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "fakerator": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-less": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-zip": "^4.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "livereactload": "^3.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react-proxy": "^1.1.8",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.4",
    "draftjs-to-html": "0.9.1",
    "fixed-data-table-2": "^0.7.17",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "pretty-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "ramda": "^0.23.0",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
    "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.22",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.4",
    "react-google-charts": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.8.0",
    "react-radio-buttons": "^1.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.3.0",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.6.8",
    "react-widgets": "^3.4.8",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^6.8.0",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

**Package-lock.json**

```
.
.
.
"react": {
  "version": "15.4.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react/-/react-15.4.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-c2wcfFQugIgScQbh9FCwEPhtFys=",
  "requires": {
    "fbjs": "^0.8.4",
    "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.0"
  }
},
   .
   . 
   .
```

Comment: The `+` and `\`` are ASCII graphics that help represent a tree structure. It’s line art.

Comment: Okay, but why does it complain about React 15.4 when that is exactly wha I have installed

Comment: Without knowing anything other than what you're saying it's impossible to guess. It might make sense to include the relevant portions of your package file (and possibly lock file) and any additional details regarding your React install.

Comment: Updated the post.